Frequent Rollback on Connection Close in Spring Boot with HikariCP and MariaDB
I'm experiencing frequent rollbacks on connection close due to a dirty commit state in my Spring Boot application using HikariCP and MariaDB. The idea is that when a user clicks 'Checkout' for an item, the inventory table is updated and the transactions table is inserted with the transaction data.
Below are the relevant excerpts from my logs, application.properties, repository, and service method.
Logs (excerpt):
2024-08-12T20:11:08.865+01:00 INFO 26316 --- [library] [ restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-08-12T20:11:09.004+01:00 INFO 26316 --- [library] [ restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.mariadb.jdbc.Connection@399e98e3
2024-08-12T20:11:09.007+01:00 INFO 26316 --- [library] [ restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-08-12T20:11:09.018+01:00 DEBUG 26316 --- [library] [ restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection : HikariPool-1 - Executed rollback on connection org.mariadb.jdbc.Connection@399e98e3 due to dirty commit state on close().

2024-08-12T20:11:09.196+01:00 DEBUG 26316 --- [library] [ restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils : 6 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO inventory (itemid, type, model, status, stock, location, company, acquisitiondate) VALUES (1, 'Hardware', 'Laptop', 'Available', 15, 'Shelf 1', 'Global Tech Solutions', '2024-06-05'), (2, 'Hardware', 'Mouse', 'Available', 15, 'Shelf 4', 'Precision Peripherals Ltd.', '2024-02-18'), (3, 'Hardware', 'Charger', 'Available', 15, 'Shelf 6', 'Charging Solutions Inc.', '2023-06-01'), (4, 'Hardware', 'Headset', 'Available', 15, 'Shelf 8', 'Audio Excellence Co.', '2023-11-11'), (5, 'Software', 'MS Office 365', 'Available', 100, NULL, 'Microsoft', '2024-10-01'), (6, 'Software', 'Adobe Creative Cloud', 'Available', 100, NULL, 'Adobe', '2024-10-01')

2024-08-12T20:11:09.987+01:00 DEBUG 26316 --- [library] [ restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2024-08-12T20:11:10.000+01:00 DEBUG 26316 --- [library] [ restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection : HikariPool-1 - Executed rollback on connection org.mariadb.jdbc.Connection@399e98e3 due to dirty commit state on close().

2024-08-12T20:11:14.389+01:00 DEBUG 26316 --- [library] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE 1=1]
2024-08-12T20:11:14.389+01:00 DEBUG 26316 --- [library] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2024-08-12T20:11:14.405+01:00 DEBUG 26316 --- [library] [nio-8080-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection : HikariPool-1 - Executed rollback on connection org.mariadb.jdbc.Connection@399e98e3 due to dirty commit state on close().

2024-08-12T20:11:17.673+01:00 TRACE 26316 --- [library] [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor : Getting transaction for [library.libraryapp.service.userInventoryService.checkoutItem]
2024-08-12T20:11:17.674+01:00 INFO 26316 --- [library] [nio-8080-exec-6] l.l.service.userInventoryService : Attempting to checkout item with ID: 2 
2024-08-12T20:11:17.689+01:00 INFO 26316 --- [library] [nio-8080-exec-6] l.l.service.userInventoryService : Current stock for item ID 2: 15        
2024-08-12T20:11:17.694+01:00 DEBUG 26316 --- [library] [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate : Executing prepared SQL update
2024-08-12T20:11:17.741+01:00 INFO 26316 --- [library] [nio-8080-exec-6] l.l.r.jdbcUserTransactionRepository : Preparing to insert transaction: library.libraryapp.model.userTransaction@31ad929c
2024-08-12T20:11:17.743+01:00 INFO 26316 --- [library] [nio-8080-exec-6] l.l.r.jdbcUserTransactionRepository : Executing SQL: INSERT INTO transactions (ItemID, UserID, CheckoutDate, DueDate, CheckinDate, Status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2024-08-12T20:11:17.751+01:00 INFO 26316 --- [library] [nio-8080-exec-6] l.l.r.jdbcUserTransactionRepository : Transaction inserted successfully: library.libraryapp.model.userTransaction@31ad929c, rows affected: 1
2024-08-12T20:11:17.757+01:00 DEBUG 26316 --- [library] [nio-8080-exec-6] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection : HikariPool-1 - Executed rollback on connection org.mariadb.jdbc.Connection@399e98e3 due to dirty commit state on close().
2024-08-12T20:11:17.759+01:00 TRACE 26316 --- [library] [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor : Completing transaction

application.properties (exceprt):
logging.file.name=application.log
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa=TRACE
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
logging.level.org.h2=DEBUG
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.pool=TRACE
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

JdbcUserTransactionRepository.java (excerpt):
@Repository
public class jdbcUserTransactionRepository implements userTransactionRepository {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(jdbcUserTransactionRepository.class);
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public jdbcUserTransactionRepository(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(userTransaction transaction) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (ItemID, UserID, CheckoutDate, DueDate, CheckinDate, Status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        logger.info("Preparing to insert transaction: {}", transaction);
        try (Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, transaction.getItemId());
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, transaction.getUserId());
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(3, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(transaction.getCheckoutDate()));
            if (transaction.getDueDate() != null) {
                preparedStatement.setDate(4, java.sql.Date.valueOf(transaction.getDueDate()));
            } else {
                preparedStatement.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.DATE);
            }
            if (transaction.getCheckinDate() != null) {
                preparedStatement.setDate(5, java.sql.Date.valueOf(transaction.getCheckinDate()));
            } else {
                preparedStatement.setNull(5, java.sql.Types.DATE);
            }
            preparedStatement.setString(6, transaction.getStatus());

            logger.info("Executing SQL: {}", preparedStatement);
            int rowsAffected = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            logger.info("Transaction inserted successfully: {}, rows affected: {}", transaction, rowsAffected);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Error inserting transaction: {}", transaction, e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

Service Method (excerpt):
    @Transactional
    public void checkoutItem(int itemId, int userId) throws Exception {
        try {
            logger.info("Attempting to checkout item with ID: {}", itemId);

            // Validate userId
            if (userRepository.findById(userId) == null) {
                logger.error("Invalid User ID: {}", userId);
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid User ID: " + userId);
            }

            userInventoryItem item = repository.findById(itemId).orElseThrow(() -> {
                logger.error("No item found with ID: {}", itemId);
                return new Exception("Item not found");
            });

            if (item.getStock() <= 0) {
                logger.error("Attempt to checkout an out of stock item ID: {}", itemId);
                throw new Exception("Item out of stock");
            }

            logger.info("Current stock for item ID {}: {}", itemId, item.getStock());
            item.setStock(item.getStock() - 1);
            repository.save(item);
            logger.info("Inventory updated for item ID: {}, new stock: {}", itemId, item.getStock());

            userTransaction transaction = new userTransaction(itemId, userId, "Pending");
            transactionRepository.save(transaction);
            logger.info("Transaction record saved successfully for item ID: {}, user ID: {}", itemId, userId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error during checkout process for item ID: {}", itemId, e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

I have edited to add my schema:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (
    UserID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Role VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Status VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active'
    );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Inventory (
    ItemID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Model VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Status VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Available',
    Stock INT,
    Location VARCHAR(255),
    Company VARCHAR(50),
    AcquisitionDate DATE NOT NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions (
TransactionID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ItemID INT NOT NULL,
UserID INT NOT NULL,
CheckoutDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
DueDate DATE,
CheckinDate DATE,
Status VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) REFERENCES Inventory(ItemID),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID)
    );

Questions:

Why am I seeing frequent rollbacks on connection close due to dirty commit state?

Is there a configuration issue in my application.properties, repository or service that could be causing this?

How can I resolve this issue to precent the rollbacks?


What I tried:

Checked configuration files

Made sure there was enough comprehensive logging.

Ensured that spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false to handle the transactions manually.



Database connection

Made sure that the database is actually connected



What I expected:

I expected that the transactions would be committed successfully, as in the transactions table has the appropriate data inserted. And that the inventory table is updated e.g. -1 inventory item upon checkout.

